# How to Insert String as DateTime with Correct Formatting in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a lot of data to insert into SQL tables, some of which are dates in the following format:

```
'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss'
```

When I insert this data, it is either switches the days and months by storing it as

```
'yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss'
```

or returns the following error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
> in an out-of-range value.

I have set the default language to British English using the following:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 23;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

But SELECT @@LANGUAGE still returns 'us_english'.

How do I insert this data without it switching the days and months?

Comment: Ideally you should be fixing your application code; is that something you can do?

Comment: As for why it's being "switched", I *assume* it's because you are using one of the older date and time data types (either `datetime` or `smalldatetime`), and for those data types formats like `yyyy-MM-dd` are *not* unambiguous; unless you're American they will be interpreted as `yyyy-dd-MM`. The reason your language isn't changing is that your `LOGIN` has a language setting too; changing the server's default language won't change the language your `LOGIN` has already had configured it'll just mean that new `LOGIN`s will have the other language set by default.

Comment: Note, as well, that it's not advisable to rely on the `LANGUAGE` setting for desired behaviour. Although changing the `LANGUAGE` of your `LOGIN` will fix the problem when *you* run the code, it won't fix it for others if they aren't using the correct language. This is why the far better solution is the fix the application code. Ideally you should be passing a date and time data type from your application to the server, not a string data type (and I **hope** you're not injecting). If you "must" pass a string type **parameter** then ensure you use either `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`.

Comment: There is no application as such, they are just mass produced import statements from another database.  I will be the only person running these statements and it should be a one-off.  Should I use another data type for the target date columns or will changing the login language suffice?

Comment: Then correct the process that is creating the statements to use `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`. That is the *real* solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any control over that, they are from a third party.

Comment: It is the language of the login that determines the interpretation. So yes, changing that is a cheap kludge as long as you always use that login for this process. Note that if your provider uses different formats over time or within a batch, you're screwed. Also note that a date is stored as a binary value and has no format. When you select those values in a query, what you actually see is a product of the application you use to visually render the resultset. Don't confuse input and ouput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the default language of my login to British English and then restarted SSMS to resolve this.

```
ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "British English"
```

String dates were thereafter interpreted correctly.